# Return xml file in WCF without reading to the memory

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a XML file (size of 10MB~), I want to return it as a `XmlDocument` type in my WCF service, but without to load it to memory before, because there are many people who request this file, so server can get an `OutOfMemory` exception.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried? Which line throws this exception? Please be more specific.

Comment: I dont have a code yet... just thinking before coding. loading a 10MB XML to the memory more then 10 time will increase the memory to up to 2-3GB ram. So I have a file called returnXML.xml, I want to return this file through the WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

If it's wcf you can use streaming (return as binary data), it was designed to handle large data:

details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)